# Python UDP socket don't work after making first connection

Tags: python, udp, client-server

I am traing to make simple application on python that works with sockets and use UDP protocol. I have a client.py and server.py. I whant to send messages from client to server in infinity loop and catch resive message from server. For making this I have following code:

**server.py**

```
import socket

serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 8000
print(host)
print(port)
serversocket.bind((host, port))

serversocket.listen(5)
print('server started and listening')
while 1:
    (clientsocket, address) = serversocket.accept()
    print("connection found!")
    data = clientsocket.recv(1024).decode()
    print(data)
    r = 'I can hear you by UDP!!!!'
    clientsocket.send(r.encode())
```

**client.py**

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 8000
addr = (host, port)
s.connect(addr)


def send(user_input):
    s.sendto(user_input.encode(), addr)
    data = s.recv(1024).decode()
    print('Server tell that: ', data)


while 1:
    if input('Exit? (y/n)') == 'y':
        break
    i = input('>> ')
    send(i)

s.close()
```

It's work correctly, but when i try to send message second time, my program make stop on line

```
s.sendto(user_input.encode(), addr)
```

I don't understand what's happening in this moment.

Comment: you'd like using udp or tcp? it seems udp&tcp method mixed up in above codes.

Comment: You're using a TCP socket here. Which is better as UDP is unreliable without defining your own checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to build server/client for UDP, you need to read the documents carefully to prevent from using the APIs which are for connection-oriented protocols.

**Below is one working sample for UDP**: (I added some comments in the codes, then you will see why adjusted them).

**Server:**

For one UDP server, you need to initialize with one socket `socket.SOCK_DGRAM` instead of `SOCK_STREAM`, then bind the port you'd like.

```
import socket

#The type of communications between the two endpoints, typically SOCK_STREAM for connection-oriented protocols and SOCK_DGRAM for connectionless protocols.
serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 8000
print(host)
print(port)
serversocket.bind((host, port))

#serversocket.listen(5)  #--This method sets up and start TCP listener.
print('server started and listening')
while 1:
    #(clientsocket, address) = serversocket.accept() #---This passively accept TCP client connection, waiting until connection arrives (blocking)
    #print("connection found!")
    #data = clientsocket.recv(1024).decode() #This method receives TCP message
    data, addr = serversocket.recvfrom(2048)
    print(data)
    r = 'I can hear you by UDP!!!!'
    serversocket.sendto(r.encode(), addr)
serversocket.close()
```

**Client:**

For one UDP client, you need to initialize one socket with `socket.SOCK_DGRAM` instead of `SOCK_STREAM`, then uses `sendto` to send the data to the server.

```
import socket
#The type of communications between the two endpoints, typically SOCK_STREAM for connection-oriented protocols and SOCK_DGRAM for connectionless protocols.
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 8000
addr = (host, port)
#s.connect(addr) #---This method actively initiates TCP server connection.


def send(user_input):
    s.sendto(user_input.encode(), addr)
    data = s.recvfrom(1024).decode()
    print('Server tell that: ', data)


while 1:
    if input('Exit? (y/n)') == 'y':
        break
    i = input('>> ')
    send(i)

s.close()
```

**For more details**:

Check [Python Socket](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/socket.html#socket.socket.sendto)